# Prove that $f(x) = x^3 -x $ is NOT Injective

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, polynomials

Okay, so I know there are plenty of injective/surjective (and thus, bijective) questions out there but I'm still not happy with the rigor of what I have done. So I'd really appreciate some help!

So the question actually asks me to do two things:

(a) give an example of a cubic function that **is** bijective. Explain why it is bijective.

(b) give an example of a cubic function that **is not** bijective. Explain why it is not bijective.

**So for (a)** I'm fairly happy with what I've done (I think):

$$ f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R , f(x) = x^3$$

So we know that to prove if a function is bijective, we must prove it is both injective and surjective.

Proof: $f$ is injective

Let: $$x,y \in \mathbb R : f(x) = f(y)$$ 
$$x^3 = y^3$$            (take cube root of both sides)
$$x=y$$

Proof: $f$ is surjective

Let: $$y \in \mathbb R$$

$$x = \sqrt[3]{y}$$

$$f(x) = (\sqrt[3]{y})^3 = y$$

So I believe that is enough to prove bijectivity for $f(x) = x^3$. Keep in mind I have cut out some of the formalities i.e. invoking definitions and sentences explaining steps to save readers time. This is just 'bare essentials'.

**So for (b)**

$$f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R , f(x) = x^3 - x$$

Now I'm just going to try and prove it is NOT injective, as that should be sufficient to prove it is NOT bijective.

Let:

$$x,y \in \mathbb R : f(x) = f(y)$$
$$x^3 - x = y^3 - y$$

This is about as far as I get. Send help. Thanks everyone.

Comment: What happens if $x=0$ or $x=1$?

Comment: To prove that a function $f$ is not injective, you just need to find two different numbers $x$ and $y$ such that $f(x)\not=f(y)$.

Comment: @Carl you mean two numbers $x,y$ such that $x\neq y$ but $f(x)=f(y)$

Comment: @CarlHeckman as JMoravitz said, you may confuse op...

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, +1's given.

Comment: @JMoravitz : Yes, you're both right! I meant $f(x)=f(y)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Injectivity:**

A function $f$ from $X\to Y$ is said to be *injective* iff the following statement holds true:

> for every $x_1,x_2\in X$ if $x_1\neq x_2$ then $f(x_1)\neq f(x_2)$

The negation of this then yields:

A function $f$ from $X\to Y$ is *not injective* iff there exists $x_1,x_2\in X$ such that $x_1\neq x_2$ but $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$

In the case of the cubic in question, it is an easily factorable polynomial and we can find multiple distinct roots.  $f(x)=x^3-x=x(x^2-1)=x(x+1)(x-1)$

We know that a root of a polynomial is a number $\alpha$ such that $f(\alpha)=0$

> So, $f(1)=f(0)=f(-1)=0$ despite $1,0,-1$ all being distinct unequal numbers in the domain.  This shows that it is not injective, and thus not bijective.

---

As an aside, one can prove that any odd degree polynomial from $\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ must be surjective by the fact that polynomials are continuous and the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: This is great. I think it has helped my understanding significantly. So what you're sort of saying is because f(1) and f(-1)  equal 0, there is more than one-to-one mapping to the elements in the co-domain (hence not injective)? So in this case the set might even look like this: {(1,0) , (-1,0)} (just as a way to visualise it)?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding (a), when you say "take cube root of both sides" you are (at least implicitly) assuming that the function is injective -- if it were not, the cube root would not be a well-defined operation.  Depending on what you are / are not allowed to assume, that could be regarded as a circular argument.

However, there is another approach.  Beginning with the assumption that $x^3=y^3$, you can manipulate the expression as follows:
$$x^3-y^3=0$$
$$(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2)=0$$
Now if you can find a convincing argument that the second factor, $x^2+xy+y^2$, is always positive for any choice of $x$ and $y$, then it follows that the only way $x^3=y^3$ can be true is if $x=y$.

The factorization $x^3-y^3=(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2)$, by the way, could also give you some insight into how to handle (b).

Comment: $$x^2+xy+y^2 = {x^2+y^2\over 2} + {1\over 2}(x^2 + 2xy+y^2) = {x^2+y^2\over 2} + {1\over2}(x+y)^2 \ge 0.$$ The only way to get equality is to have $x=0$ and $y=0$, but then $x=y$ in that case as well.

Comment: @CarlHeckman  Yes, I know.  Also $x^2+xy+y^2 = (x + \frac{1}{2}y)^2 + \frac{3}{4}y^2$.  I was intentionally leaving that out to leave the OP something to finish.